On Theorem 2.7 of Montgomery and Vaughan's MNT
In Theorem 2.7 of Montgomery and Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory, they show that a constant arising in an earlier calculation is precisely the Euler-Mascheroni constant. While I understand the overall proof, I am having trouble with certain bounds they establish toward the end. Specifically, they derive that
$$\delta \int_1^\infty \frac{x^{-1-\delta}}{\log 2x} \, dx 
\ll \delta + \delta \int_2^{e^{1/\delta}} \frac{dx}{x \log x} 
+ \delta^2 \int_{e^{1/\delta}}^\infty x^{-1-\delta} \, dx 
\ll \delta \log \frac{1}{\delta}.$$
It appears that the integral was split into three regions: $[1,2]$, $[2, e^{1/\delta}]$, and $[e^{1/\delta}, \infty)$. It is very likely that the bounds exploit the behavior of the integrand in each region, but I am struggling to reconstruct the details (I should also add that $\delta \rightarrow 0^{+}$).
Could someone explain how these bounds were obtained?

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\delta\in\left(0,\log\left(2\right)\right)$ since, if I remember correctly, in that theorem we want to take $\delta\rightarrow0^{+}$. Then $$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^{-1-\delta}}{\log\left(2x\right)}dx\leq\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^{-1}}{\log\left(2x\right)}dx\ll1$$
since the last integral is obviously finite. Next, we observe that if $x\in\left(2,e^{1/\delta}\right)$ we clearly have $\log\left(2x\right)>\log\left(x\right)$, so $$\int_{2}^{e^{1/\delta}}\frac{x^{-1-\delta}}{\log\left(2x\right)}dx\leq\int_{2}^{e^{1/\delta}}\frac{x^{-1}}{\log\left(x\right)}dx=\log\left(\log\left(e^{1/\delta}\right)\right)-\log\left(\log\left(2\right)\right)=$$ $$=\log\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)-\log\left(\log\left(2\right)\right)\leq2\log\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)$$ since $\delta\in\left(0,\log\left(2\right)\right)$. The last integrall follows from the fact that if $x\in\left(e^{1/\delta},+\infty\right)$, then $$\log\left(2x\right)>\log\left(2e^{1/\delta}\right)=\log\left(2\right)+\frac{1}{\delta}$$ hence $$\int_{e^{1/\delta}}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-1-\delta}}{\log\left(2x\right)}dx\leq\frac{1}{\log\left(2\right)+1/\delta}\int_{e^{1/\delta}}^{+\infty}x^{-1-\delta}dx\leq\delta\int_{e^{1/\delta}}^{+\infty}x^{-1-\delta}dx\ll1$$ where the last term obviously does not depend on $\delta$. Since we are interested to take $\delta\rightarrow0^{+}$, is clear that the dominant term is $\log\left(1/\delta\right)$. Then, the result follows.
